# How to get subset of existing fileset

Tags: php, build, phing

I have following target in my build.xml prepared to being processed by Phing:

```
<target name="syntax-test">
    <exec command="git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB" dir="./" escape="false" output="${TMP_DIR}/changed_files" />
    <fileset id="CHANGED_FILES" dir="./" includesfile="${TMP_DIR}/changed_files" />
    </exec>

    <phplint haltonfailure="true" level="warning" deprecatedAsError="true">
        <fileset refid="CHANGED_FILES" />
    </phplint>
</target>
```

As I have many tools, which I want to run only above small subset of all files - only on those, which were added/modified/etc., I need to filter these.

This works fine.

Each tool is very specific and can be used for checking only specific files (like **phplint** for checking **.php** or **xmllint** for checking **.xml**).

How do I filter out these?

When I'm trying to apply **patternset** or includes, it seems it's forced to use only the new rules (ignores **includesfile** parameter).

Answer (score 1):

As **FileSet** accepts [filename](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/current/chapters/appendixes/AppendixD4-CoreSelectors.html#Filename) as a nested tag, you can use it:

```
<fileset id="CHANGED_FILES" dir="./" includesfile="${TMP_DIR}/changed_files">
    <filename name="**/*.php" />
</fileset>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me works **.php instead of **/*.php

```
<fileset id="CHANGED_FILES" dir="./" includesfile="${TMP_DIR}/changed_files">
    <filename name="**.php" />
</fileset>
```